# Deleting a specific session key from Express/Mongo

Tags: mongodb, session, express

Im using Express sessions with the Mongo store. In the below sample code, if I write the `delete` before `const result`, it works properly and `session.message` will be deleted from MongoDB.

```
    exports.getIndex = function(req, res) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated())
        return res.redirect('/panel');

    delete req.session.messages;
    const result = res.render('login', {title: 'Gmail Project', error: req.session.messages});

    return result;
    }
```

But if I write the delete statement after `cont result` like below, I guess, the session should be deleted in the next request. But session won't be deleted in this case.

```
exports.getIndex = function(req, res) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated())
        return res.redirect('/panel');


    var result = res.render('login', {title: 'Gmail Project', error: req.session.messages});
    delete req.session.messages;

    return result;
}
```

Also, this is the order of my middleware uses in `app.js` file,

```
app.use(expressSession({
  secret: 'marandipedro',
  maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),  
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(messages.flushMessages());
```

Routes are defined after these lines.

Comment: please provide more code, specially how and in which order you are using your middlewares and `express-session` middleware

Comment: @KayvanMazaheri Edited.